# How do I customize y-axis labels and randomly pick the value from the data range for x-axis in Chart js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, chart.js2

I have been working on a chart using charts.js that show workouts duration each day. The y-axis should have dates and the x-axis should have the duration of the Series,
Here is my dataset:

```
    public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 19, 40, 81, 56, 5, 40], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [95, 69, 40, 81, 56, 96, 40], label: 'Series B' },
    { data: [65, 74, 40, 41, 54, 55, 40], label: 'Series C' }
  ];
  public lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['2020/05/20', '2020/05/21', '2020/05/22', '2020/05/23', '2020/05/24', '2020/05/25'];
```

So far I am unable to find any implementation-related it, it would be very helpful if anyone can help me out on this.
I have tried the stackblitz with horizontal with a bar chart, we need to same like in LINE CHART
Here is stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartsforlinegraph?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [`scatter`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) chart and define the option `showLine: true` on each dataset. Further you have to define the y-axis as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) as follows.

```
yAxes: [
  {
    type: "time",
    time: {
      parser: "YYYY/MM/DD",
      unit: "day",
      displayFormats: {
        day: "YYYY/MM/DD"
      }
    },
    ticks: {
      reverse: true
    }       
  }
]
```

Since the scatter chart expects the data in [point format](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#data-structure), you have to generate appropriate data structure in the `ngOnInit` method as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.lineChartData.forEach(ds => {
    ds.data = ds.data.map((v, i) => ({ x: v, y:  this.lineChartLabels[i] }));
  });
}
```

Also remove `[labels]="lineChartLabels"` from the `canvas`, this is not needed when defining the data in point format.

> Unfortunately however `ng2-charts` can't cope with this configuration and displays wrong colors for the data points and the legend labels. Therefore I also had to remove `[colors]="lineChartColors"` from the `canvas` and define the colors on the datasets.
> You'll probably have to get rid of this wrapper library and use Chart.js directly in order to obtain the expected result.

Please take a look at your amended code in this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-y-time-axis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you for giving the solution, 
 this.lineChartData.forEach(ds => {
      ds.data = ds.data.map((v, i) => ({ x: v, y:  this.lineChartLabels[i] }));
    });

the above one is not working in angular and Is the way to use dynamic data convert the scatter chart data. (ChartDataSets)